# Create class diagram from already existent iphone code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, class, uml, diagram

does anybody know, how i could create automatically a UML class diagram from an already existent iphone project. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/277/7284_reverseengin.html Instant reverse Objective-C may be helpful for you

Comment: seems these two questions are duplicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873606/how-can-i-automatically-generate-uml-diagrams-from-objective-c-code

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/):

1. Install Doxygen (with MacPorts: `sudo port install doxygen`).
2. Get a script like [this](https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/blob/master/doxygen.sh) and change the first lines to match your configuration.
3. Download [these files](https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/tree/master/sources/doxygen) and edit the Doxygen file so it says `HAVE_DOT=YES` and `UML_LOOK=YES`.

It will then generate and install a docset that you can read from the documentation browser, or just right click and show contents from Finder.

---

Or, if you want a graph of dependencies check: https://github.com/nst/objc_dep It uses graphviz.

Comment: The links in this post are dead. Are there updated links?

Comment: I fixed the links, Idk if that method still works, it’s 11 years old and intended for Objective-C projects. These days I make diagrams manually with OmniGraffle, tho the technology pieces to automate this process are already floating around.

Answer (score 14):

See also [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) of all things. If you open an Xcode project with it, it will generate a full class diagram. It can be fairly overwhelming for a large project.

Comment: Crashes every time on larger projects, regardless of trial or paid.

Comment: My experience with OmniGraffle is the same as Oh Danny Boy's.

Comment: Same here. I could get it working only when I created dummy project and imported only files I need there. Crashes very often. Also the diagram it generates is absolute garbage. Does not show @property in diagram. Bad bad tool.

Comment: This happened for me when i tried to have it also import "frameworks", but unchecking that, it stopped crashing