# How can I automatically generate UML diagrams from Objective-C code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uml

Is there a way to create automatically the UML diagram from the code, in objective-C ?

Cheers,
Niels

Comment: Hah! Since you've already built it, why bother with documentation? :)

Comment: because i won't be in charge of the project anymore.

Comment: OmniGraffle used to have a feature where you could drop an Xcode project on it and it'd generate class files automatically. I'm not sure if it still does though. epatel's probably closer to the answer with looking at Doxygen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html). Which seem to have support for Objective-C. It might not give you an UML diagram but it is able to show references etc in graphs and with added comments you can give more information for the formatted output.

See here for an example in Objective-C, [the clang project](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BlockPointerType.html) (oups, clang is actually written in C++ and works on Objective-C code) But I found this [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20130923000537/http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/) about using doxygen for Objective-C code

Comment: That blog post is no longer available.

Answer (score 13):

Same problem, still looking for answer:

- Checked **Doxygen**, but I could generate only documentation and graph fragments. Maybe should spend some quality time with documentation
- Checked **OmniGraffle**, output was kind of ok. Run out of free demo period and not going buy full version ONLY for a few occasional graphs. Might be ok, if you have some other uses for it. Not sure, if OmniGraffle "officially" supports that any more

Finally found ["**objc_dep**.py" from GitHub](https://github.com/nst/objc_dep). It's free, fast, simple and works as-is. It generates a kind of "dependency graph" based on imports, which really isn't UML or class diagrams, but was surprisingly close enough.

So that's what I'm using now, but non-actively looking for something "more". Blogged about the objc_dep tool in "[Dependency Graph Tool for iOS Projects](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2012/01/dependency-graph-tool-for-ios-projects.html)", might be interesting if you want more info with sample graphs.

...but looking for something to generate real class diagrams.

Comment: Could use http://graphviz.org/Download_macos.php to open the .dot file generated by the Python script

Comment: I use simple "open file.dot -a GraphViz" in Mac terminal, when the generated file is called file.dot.

Answer (score -1):

There is no proper solution to create a UML diagram from Reverse Engineering code. 
I tried all the above methods including the python code. 
The python code though useful fails if you have a huge project, which unfortunately was my case.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: With python you mean the objc_dep.py graph generator? Never seen it fail, even with some rather big and messy codebases. Can you give me (anything) about the failures, might check it out and fix?

Comment: I had almost 2000 classes with inter-linkages. The graph that came up with the python code was so complex and huge that i couldn't view it at all. I tried to do it with individual packages then and separately used them.

Comment: Heh, that kind of failure :) There's now filters to skip over certain classes or subdirectories. Might help a bit, but the output still depends on project: if it's messy, it WILL look messy.