# UML diagram reverse engineered from iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, uml, class-diagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I generate UML diagrams from Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079312/how-can-i-generate-uml-diagrams-from-xcode4)

I need to create UML diagrams from iOS projects. IS there a tool for this that can reverse engineer the code and create the Class Diagrams and UML.

I have a huge project that we have created over the last 1 year, and now we have to create the

Documentation.

Thanks
Pradeep.

Comment: Mabye this link will help you on the way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873606/how-can-i-automatically-generate-uml-diagrams-from-objective-c-code Some good answers in this post.
Hope it helps :D