# how can I automatically create a class diagram from Objective-C 2.0 and Xcode 5/6

Tags: class-diagram, objective-c-2.0

I have been reviewing similar questions and all answers refer me to either OmniGraffle, which is not really intended for the task, or to other tools that are not designed for Objective-C. I have found a python script that graphs dependencies through imports, but so far I have had no real luck. There are many tools for other languages, is it possible that nobody supports Objective-C? I mean, is there really not a tool that will read all .h and .m files from a project and produce a decent class diagram?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424362/create-class-diagram-from-already-existent-iphone-code

Comment: I had some old code to do this, you injected it in your application and it produced a .dot file that you could render with graphviz or OmniGraffle. I think I'll undust it and post it to github

Answer (score 0):

Visual paradigm is another option.

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool